# Change the file-name in tblwrite when created table

Tags: matlab

I want to create 15 txt tables with different names by using  tblwrite in matlab. my attempt was in this code

```
for j=1:15
rownames=char(rownames1(:,j));
T(:,1)=[1:length(K_minus_t)];
table=char(T(j,1));
colnames{j}={'lambda_L';'C_L';'lambda_N';'tau_N';'lambda_c';'tau_c';};
values{j}=[coef_line lam_tau_curve lam_tau_cap];
tblwrite(values{j},colnames{j},rownames,'table.txt');
end
```

unfortunately, it was failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: You are writing 15 times to the same file (named 'table.txt'). Change the name. Also, avoid posting questions saying "it fails". Give information on the error you get.

Comment: seb,My question is that how can I change the name I have problem with the name because the code save all the data in one table I need 15 with different name

Comment: just replace `'table.txt'` by `sprintf('table_%02i.txt', j)`

Comment: Thanks..The code is working now